# Invoke AWS API Gateway Private not accessible from Front but EC2 works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to invoke an AWS API Gateway Private from React JS Front which is deployed on EC2 instance, and I'm getting: **POST https://abcdefghi0123456.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stage/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**.

Here are the conditions:

1. OK - The Private API Gateway is associated to a VPCE (VPC Endpoint) to have access and invoke a Lambda (which is inside in a VPC)
2. OK - POST Test from API's method to invoke Lambda (VPC)
3. OK - POST Test from EC2 instance command line, here a sample of curl command:

   curl --location --request POST 'https://abcdefghi0123456.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stage/' 
   --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
   --data-raw '{
   "my_key": "my_value"
   }'
4. ERROR - POST from React JS build deployed inside same EC2 instance

Note:

- OK - Invoking an AWS Public API Gateway
- A sample of Policy attached to the Private API Gateway:

  {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
  {
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789123:abcde1abc2/*/*/*",
  "Condition": {
  "StringNotEquals": {
  "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-0abc12d34567e8901"
  }
  }
  },
  {
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:123456789123:abcde1abc2/*/*/*"
  }
  ]
  }

Comment: `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`  seems as error from browser. Where do you actual invoke your api?

Comment: Currently i invoke the API from React JS deployed on EC2 instance inside a VPC.

Comment: Isn't ReactJS for frontend? So your code will actually execute in the browser, not on the ec2 instance as if you were using php or python?

Comment: Sure, ReactJS is for frontend. The code is Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ReactJS does not work, because the JavaScript code that calls your API executes on the **client side**, such as a web browser.

This requires **public API gateway** which can work over the Internet, not private one which is only valid within a VPC. The private API will work only from the backend code that executes on the instance, as you verified using `curl`, and it can't be invoked over the Internet. Subsequently, it will not work on the client side.

To make your API gateway invokable from a client side, it must be changed to a public API.

Comment: Thanks, How can I secure the API Gateway? As I understand I must to put it inside inside the VPC.

Comment: @ambigus9 If the api should be public, you could use Lambda authorizers or Amazon Cognito. API in VPC, is only for use inside VPC, not from the internet as you have it now.

Comment: Thanks, Currently the App has been develop on ReactJS and has Amplify App and AWS Amazon Cognito to autenticate the Federation of users. Is that a secure solution?

Comment: @ambigus9 secure in what sense? This is how it is usually done.

Comment: In sense of that the data is protected. Is there a way to put Amplify and Cognito inside the VPC? I'm new in this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ambigus9 You can't put them in VPC, they are meant for internet access, not internal access.

Comment: Thanks! You solved my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ambigus9 No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Comment: A good way to protect the API is associate a AWS WAF to the Public API Gateway?

Comment: @ambigus9 WAF can also be useful, but its not for authentication like cognito. You could make new question with your objectives of how to secure API, as its difficult to say exactly what are your requirements based on the comments only.